# routProvider controller inside of html file

Tags: html, angularjs, controller

I can do something like this?

```
$routeProvider.when('/developer/logs', {
        templateUrl: '/themes/default/template/developer_logs.html',
        controller: "DeveloperLogsCtrl"
    });
```

and in developer_logs.html

```
<script>
app.controller('DeveloperLogsCtrl', function($location, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.PageTitle= 'Developer Logs';
});
</script>

<div class="content-heading">
    <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <h1>Logs</h1>
        <li><a href="/">Dashboard</a>
        </li>
        <li>Developer</li>
        <li class="active">Logs</li>
    </ol>        
</div>

<div>asfa8fhfga</div>
```

I tried but I get http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/ng/areq?p0=DeveloperLogsCtrl&p1=not%20a

Answer (score 0):

You can't lazy load angular code within templates.

There is no built in lazy load mechanism either without using third party modules.

Include all your components in initial page load or look for third party load managers

Comment: You destroyed my dream.